# Branding Resources: Custom Envelope Fields

Tags: docusignapi

I'm modifying the Email Resource under branding in the DocuSign portal.

I understand you can add defaults fields, such as Recipient Name, such as:

```
Dear [[Data:RecipientName]],
```

What I want to do is show information from the Envelope Custom Fields, so if I created custom field called Department, I would like to do the following:

```
Dear [[Data:RecipientName]] from the [[Data:Department]] Team,
```

I tried to add this in, but I get the following error when reviewing it in the account branding page:

```
TextTemplateEngine::ProcessTemplate() Cannot find token replacement for token Department, cannot continue.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible. If you wanted to accomplish such a behavior you would need to pass in all the custom text for the email body using the emailBlurb property in the API.

Comment: Luis' response should be an answer.

Comment: OK, how do I get formatting and paragraphs, as emailBlurb does not accept HTML tags?

Comment: If you're using the API DocuSign can turn HTML on for the EmailBlurb if you ask.  The web console doesn't allow for HTML though.